# Can we bio-engineer freewill?

Tags: philosophy-of-biology

Following from the title more specifically: let's say for example I'm a behaviorist and believe that species A has more freewill than species B (by noticing breeding complexity in breeding patterns). Now, to formalize this I can see outliers of the species A and B and using retrodictions I see a pattern. Let's assume I can create a species by interbreeding A and B ... Now from a retrodictions versus prediction perspective how do we even presume after finite interations we still have a normalizable distribution?

Comment: Depends on what type of free will you believe in. Libertarian free will? Possibly not. Reasons-responsive compatibilist free will? Yeah, maybe.

Comment: Re. the biological component, it could get a bit complicated to answer.

Comment: It seems totally unlear how you define free will, quantify free will and observe the degree of free will in behavioral experiments. That makes your whole post questionable.

Comment: I personally don't think one can define freewill as above ... But from an experimental perspective it might be useful

Comment: No, free will requires quantum entanglement which biological brains are too warm to support. Only helium-cooled quantum computers can have free will. /s

Comment: @caisative I thought it was a properly of the universe